# How to Dither an image using Floyd-Steinberg algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, dithering

I'm new to C# and for my second project I'm trying to write an algorithm that dithers a Bitmap using Floyd-Steinberg method, I followed Coding Trains Video but I get a bunch of errors where RGB values are out of bounds, for example, some times values are 256 and sometimes it's even negatives.

Here is the important chunk of code.

```
static public Bitmap Imagedither(Bitmap original)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < original.Height - 1; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < original.Width - 1; x++)
        {
            Color oldPixel = original.GetPixel(x, y);
            Color newPixel = roundColor(oldPixel, 1);
            original.SetPixel(x, y, newPixel);
            Error error = new Error(oldPixel.R - newPixel.R, oldPixel.G - newPixel.G, oldPixel.B - newPixel.B);

            original.SetPixel(x + 1, y    , AddError(original.GetPixel(x + 1, y), error, 7 / 16.0));
            original.SetPixel(x - 1, y + 1, AddError(original.GetPixel(x - 1, y + 1), error, 3 / 16.0));
            original.SetPixel(x    , y + 1, AddError(original.GetPixel(x, y + 1), error, 5 / 16.0));
            original.SetPixel(x + 1, y + 1, AddError(original.GetPixel(x + 1, y + 1), error, 1 / 16.0));
        }
    }
    return original;
}

static public Color roundColor(Color color, int factor)
{
    double R = (double)factor * color.R / 255.0;
    double newR = Math.Round(R) * (255 / factor);
    double G = (double)factor * color.G / 255.0;
    double newG = Math.Round(G) * (255 / factor);
    double B = (double)factor * color.B / 255.0;
    double newB = Math.Round(B) * (255 / factor);
    return Color.FromArgb((int)newR, (int)newG, (int)newB);
}

static public Color AddError(Color pixel, Error error, double amount)
{
    int R = (int)(pixel.R + (error.R * amount));
    int G = (int)(pixel.G + (error.G * amount));
    int B = (int)(pixel.B + (error.B * amount));
    return Color.FromArgb(R > 255 ? 255 : R, G > 255 ? 255 : G, B > 255 ? 255 : B);
}

public class Error
{
    public double R { get; set; }
    public double G { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
    public Error() { }
    public Error(double r, double g, double b)
    {
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: @TaW I don't think so, because everywhere I looked everyone had 255, even Coding Train.

Comment: You are right. Which lines come up with the errors? Doesn't the debugger help? -  This line can create negative values: `Error error = new Error(oldPixel.R - newPixel.R, oldPixel.G - newPixel.G, oldPixel.B `- newPixel.B);` - Instead of limiting only too large values you need to clamp them on both sides, maybe like so `int R = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(255,(int)(pixel.R + (error.R * amount))));`..

Comment: @Taw Your solution worked, but I am still wondering why it needed to be clamped. Oh, and the error comes up on the line `return Color.FromArgb(R > 255 ? 255 : R, G > 255 ? 255 : G, B > 255 ? 255 : B);` I think there is some kind of error in calculating the RGB values and the Class Error can have negative values.